# Standalone Gazebo crashes on startup

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Following NKoenig's advice from [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/761/how-do-i-update-from-the-fuerte-gazebo-release-to/), I tried to install standalone Gazebo (using [these instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.3/install)).

The version of gazebo that comes with ROS works fine, but the standalone crashes:

When I run "gazebo" from the command line, I get

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
```

It starts to load. Instead of the usual "world", I see a black square. After waiting a couple more minutes, I see a white sky appear.  Waiting a little while longer, I see the usual cloud background. Then the program crashes with no error messages.

Sometimes it crashes earlier and I get this message:

```
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InvalidParametersException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): All framebuffer formats with this texture internal format unsupported in GLFrameBufferObject::initialise at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-visualization-common-1.8.4/debian/ros-fuerte-visualization-common/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLFrameBufferObject.cpp (line 276)
```

Also noteworthy: starting Gazebo with "sudo gazebo" gives:

```
gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: liburdfdom_model.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling.
- Running as root
- Uninstalling ROS using apt-get --purge remove ros-*  and reinstalling Gazebo.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with the proprietary NVIDIA drivers for my NVIDIA Corporation NV45GL [Quadro FX 3400/4400] graphics card.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/812/standalone-gazebo-crashes-on-startup/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solution: Install 64 bit Ubuntu rather than 32 bit Ubuntu.  Though, it runs much much slower than the ROS versions of Gazebo do.

---

Originally posted by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) with karma: 175 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0